# How to write a post request to the server when the mock data is off?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Неllo! I need help.

I have these data - tree terms in the store.

How to write a post-request to the server to sync terms in Vue components methods, when the mockdata is off.

P.S. Нow can use Axios?

```
  methods: {
    onTermCreate(newTerm) {
      const actionName = this.getModuleActionName('term', ACTIONS_NAMES.CREATE_TERM);
      this.$store.dispatch(actionName, newTerm).then(() => {
        // TODO add post request to sync terms state with server, then reset form //
        this.showPostRequestData();
        this.resetForm();
      })
    },

    addNewDataToExistingTerm(existingTerm, newTerm) {
      existingTerm.parents.push(newTerm);
      const actionName = this.getModuleActionName('term', ACTIONS_NAMES.UPDATE_TERM);
      this.$store.dispatch(actionName, existingTerm).then(() => {
        // TODO add post request to sync terms state with server, then reset form //
        this.showPostRequestData();
        this.resetForm();
      })
    }
 }
```

Comment: what do you mean: when the mock data is off ?

Comment: @AhmadMobaraki I have a toggle switch, I can show data from the store when demonstrating a project without a working server.

Answer (score 0):

Put all your API calls inside Actions in your Vuex store. This way every change that gets committed to your state only comes from inside the store and makes it easier for you to debug and make the code easier to understand.

Now to use axios you should do something like this:

```
state = {
   // 
},
getters = {
  //
},
mutations = {
    SET_TERM : (state,payload) => {
      state.term = payload
    }
},
actions = {
  CREATE_TERM : async (context,payload) => {
      let { data } = await Axios.get('/path/to/api/')
      context.commit('SET_TODO',data)
  }
}
```

Please read this [awesome article](https://medium.com/dailyjs/mastering-vuex-zero-to-hero-e0ca1f421d45)  for more explanations and details.